# Flutter Handshake exception: TLSV1 Decode error

Tags: flutter, networking, dio

I try to connect with a server with self-signed tls certificate (which will raise NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error if I visit the same url via Chrome). The url is an IP address, instead of a named website. However, it shows the following error message in Flutter debug console:

```
Error: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR(tls_record.cc:592))
```

I've tried to force the flutter to trust the certificate anyway with the following code:

```
 _dio.httpClientAdapter = IOHttpClientAdapter(
     createHttpClient: () {
       final HttpClient client = HttpClient(context: SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false));

       client.badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) {
          return true;
       };

       return client;
     },
     validateCertificate: (certificate, host, port) {
       return true;
     },
 );
```

The `client.badCertificateCallback` and `validateCertificate` callbacks are never reached, which means the error occurs even before the certificate validation process.

I also found a similar issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49183
,but with Dart 3.1.3 I am still experiencing the same error message. I tried to capture packets, but the data is different from the one in GitHub. There is no TLSv1.x protocol (in my case tls 1.3 is used), but something called gearman. I am attaching the packets traffic here: [image]

I am not familiar with network, but it seems that things gets weird after the first 3 TCP packets. There should be a client hello after that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!